# Mapping shared drive works from my local machine but not from a Windows Server 2012r2

Tags: windows, networking, nas, windows-server-2012, mapped-drive

I have an issue with mapping NAS drive in win server.

1. I can map it from my local machine, I cannot map it from this server. I have done everything and still cannot get through it.
2. Server has static IP
3. No firewalls
4. **I can ping the NAS but cannot net view or net use**
   The error I get is when net use Z: \<*server_ip*>\<*share*> is :

   ***System error 64 has occurred. The specified network name is no longer 
   available.***
5. Even when I try to map the share from Network folder, I get the same error
6. Have tried to check for all services that must be enabled, they seem ok

It would be immensely helpful if someone could assist,

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution, it was related to routing, simply executing the following command fixed the issue: 
**route add 192.168.1.0 mask 255.255.255.0 192.168.220.2 -p**

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a network hardware or network driver issue.  This was sometimes a common error back in Vista because it introduced a SMB v2.  This error now shows up again as Server 2012 introduced SMB v3.

See if there are any updates for your NAS. *Note that there are a lot of NAS devices out there that still only support SMB 1.  SMB 1 support was dropped in Server 2012 and Windows 8.1.*

Also check your drivers.  What version of windows is your local machine running?